# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Confirmation page after Create Post Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like have a confirmation page displayed to the end user after he/she submits their information on the Create page on the values that they entered and selected from the two drop down lists. I'm not sure the best way to handle this and could use some help.

I'm going to post my code that I have now below. I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0, C#, Entity Framework Core Code First and SQL Server 2016.

**Models**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public string TimeSlot { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModels**

```
public class EmployeeFormVM
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your First Name")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Last Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your Department")]
    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your Appointment")]
    [Display(Name = "Appointment")]
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class WinTenDbContext : DbContext
{
    public WinTenDbContext(DbContextOptions<WinTenDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasKey(e => e.EmployeeID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(e => e.FirstName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();


        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(e => e.LastName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();            

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasKey(d => d.DepartmentID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .Property(d => d.Name)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>()
            .HasKey(a => a.AppointmentID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>()
            .Property(a => a.TimeSlot)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

**EmployeesController**

```
public class EmployeesController : Controller
{
    private readonly WinTenDbContext _context;

    public EmployeesController(WinTenDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Employees and their Departments
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var webAppDbContext = _context.Employees.Include(d => d.Department).Include(a => a.Appointment);
        return View(await webAppDbContext.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Employees/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employee = await _context.Employees
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
        //var appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
        //var appointments = _context.Appointments.Where(x => !x.Employees.Any());
        var appointments = _context.Appointments.Include(x => x.Employees).Where(x => !x.Em‌​ployees.Any()).ToLis‌​t();

        var viewModel = new EmployeeFormVM
        {
            Departments = departments,
            Appointments = appointments
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // POST: Employees/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(EmployeeFormVM employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var emp = new Employee();
            {
                emp.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
                emp.LastName = employee.LastName;
                emp.DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID;
                emp.AppointmentID = employee.AppointmentID;
            }

            // Query DB to check if Employee exists with same First/Last Name
            Employee existingEmployee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FirstName == employee.FirstName && m.LastName == employee.LastName);
            if (existingEmployee != null)
            {
                // Display Error if duplicate employee
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "An employee with this name has already registered. Please contact the Service Desk for any scheduling conflicts.");
                employee.Departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
                //employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                return View(employee);
            }

            // Query DB to check if appointment has already been assigned to an employee
            Employee existingAppointment = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AppointmentID == employee.AppointmentID);
            if (existingAppointment != null)
            {
                // Display error if the appointment was already chosen
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "This appointment has already been taken. Please select another timeslot.");
                employee.Departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
                //employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                return View(employee);
            }

            _context.Add(emp);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(employee);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employeevm = new EmployeeFormVM();
        {
            Employee employee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);

            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            employeevm.EmployeeID = employee.EmployeeID;
            employeevm.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
            employeevm.LastName = employee.LastName;

            // Retrieve list of Departments
            var departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
            employeevm.Departments = departments;
            // Set the selected department
            employeevm.DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID;

            // Retrieve list of Appointments
            var appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
            employeevm.Appointments = appointments;
            // Set the selected department
            employeevm.AppointmentID = employee.AppointmentID;
        }   
        return View(employeevm);
    }

    // POST: Employees/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EmployeeFormVM vmEdit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Employee employee = _context.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeID == vmEdit.EmployeeID);

            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            employee.FirstName = vmEdit.FirstName;
            employee.LastName = vmEdit.LastName;
            employee.DepartmentID = vmEdit.DepartmentID;
            employee.AppointmentID = vmEdit.AppointmentID;

            try
            {
                _context.Update(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!EmployeeExists(vmEdit.EmployeeID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(vmEdit);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employee = await _context.Employees
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    // POST: Employees/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var employee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
        _context.Employees.Remove(employee);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool EmployeeExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Employees.Any(e => e.EmployeeID == id);
    }
}
```

**Create View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employees"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "validation-summary-errors" })
        //@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @style = "color: #cc0000" })
        //@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.LastName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.DepartmentID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(d => d.DepartmentID, new SelectList(Model.Departments, "DepartmentID", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.DepartmentID)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.AppointmentID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.AppointmentID, new SelectList(Model.Appointments, "AppointmentID", "TimeSlot"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AppointmentID)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: You can just serialize the form and store it in a hidden field of the confirmation page. When the user approves of the action, you just post the content in the hidden field to your desired action method with an additional information on the user approval for the save. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're redirecting to an index page after a successful `Create()` call:

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
```

If you'd like to show the user a confirmation that their employee has been created, a common pattern in UI design is to instead redirect to the details page for the newly created resource:

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
var newlyCreatedId = emp.EmployeeId;
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Details), new { id = newlyCreatedId }));
```

Comment: I was able to retrieve the First and Last Name on the Details page like you mentioned above. However, I'm not able to get the information for the Appointment and Department. I need the Appointment.TimeSlot value and the Department.Name value.

Answer (score 0):

It's incredibly unclear what you're looking for here. You're already implementing the PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern, so there should be no issue.

If the problem is simply that you're currently redirecting to `Index`, and you'd rather go to something like `Confirmation`, that's as simple as just changing the `RedirectToAction` line, accordingly.

If the issue is that you want to redisplay the posted data on that confirmation page, following the redirect, then you need to either include some way to retrieve it again (e.g. `/success/{id}/`, enabling you to retrieve it via that id) or you need to persist it in the session store (either `Session` or `TempData`, though `TempData` is probably more appropriate in this scenario).

Comment: Yes, I would like to change the RedirectToAction to confirmation instead of Index. Then on the Confirmation page I would like to display the values that the end user entered/selected from the drop down lists.

Comment: Then, there you go. Change the action you're redirecting to, and before you direct either set `TempData` with those values, or include the id of a record that contains those values with the redirect, and look them up from the database in your confirmation action.